# Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup

Tags: android, bluetooth

when opening a bluetooth rfcomm socket via the UUID method ( the other method  ( using reflection ) in here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5427 ) - I sometimes get the following error  ( after successfull connections ) and the socket is not opened:

```
E/BluetoothService(21847): Received ACTION_UPDATE_SERVICE_CACHE00:0B:CE:01:2E:00
D/BluetoothService(21847): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:0B:CE:01:2E:00)
D/BluetoothService(21847): Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: 00:0B:CE:01:2E:00 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

had no luck with google on this one - has anyone here a clue whats going on and how to prevent that?

**Update:**

for people running into the same problem - possible solutions:

1. advice the users to reboot the device if we run into that state (
   very bad UX )
2. use the reflection method ( dirty but works most of the time )
3. I am still open for new Ideas ;-)

I stick to #2 at the moment - but waiting for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the message is the consequence, not the reason. If a serial port emulation service is not found on device the connection will obviously fail.

**Update**

After reviewing [code](https://github.com/ligi/DUBwise-Commons/blob/master/src/org/ligi/android/io/BluetoothCommunicationAdapter.java) everything seems ok. So my questions are: Do the random errors occur with same device o with different devices? If the occur with different devices, the devices might have not registered the SerialPort service. Is device previously paired? In case of the error ocurring randomly with same device? Are you using the connection class concurrently? You have not protected the methods against concurrent access. You have not protected either against succesive connects. If you try to read/close a stream after a second connect it will fail (the socket object has changed).

It seems ok. The random error occurs with same device? If this is the case, are you using concurrent use of that class? In first case

Comment: the service is existing - I am able to connect this way on this device - just sometimes I get that error ( for a while ) and some connection attempts later it is working - but I want to get rid of the delay caused by that problem ..

Comment: You may only connect to a service if it has been descovered first. On J2ME it works so. So what I assume is that you are launching a discovery task and parelly you are connecting to the service. Sometimes the discovery may fail so assumes the device has no such device.

Comment: Interestingly these modules do not even do SDP Service discovery - I am pretty sure only to open the port at this particular moment - was easier with J2ME because you can directly connect to port and skip SDP totally.

Comment: Could you post a piece of code so we can figure out what is going on?

Comment: sure: https://github.com/ligi/DUBwise-Commons/blob/master/src/org/ligi/android/io/BluetoothCommunicationAdapter.java